# Grouping streaming data in pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark, delta-lake

I have two delta tables I'm reading, joining and writing. They both have timestamps, so I'm using those as watermarks and I can join the data without problems. However, when I try to group it, the stream doesn't write anything to the delta anymore.

```py
actionResult = actionResult.withColumnRenamed("timestamp", "secTimestamp") \
  .withWatermark("secTimestamp", "1 day")
combi = action.join(actionResult, 
          (action.actionID == actionResult.actionID) & 
           expr("secTimestamp < timestamp + interval 1 day"), 
        how="left") \ 
  .drop("secTimestamp").drop(actionResult.actionID) # still able to write

combi = combi.withWatermark("timestamp", "1 day") \
  .groupby("ShipmentID", F.window("timestamp", "1 day", "1 day")) \
  .agg(sparkMax(col('timestamp')).alias("timestamp"),
    collect_list('HubID').alias('HubID')) # no results
```

Any insights on what might be wrong?

Comment: No sure, but on 1st glance your .agg at end might be leaking with brackets? Not sure, but  might.

Comment: @pinegulf thanks for your comment! But I think they are correct, both collect_list and sparkMax(col('timestamp')) should be inside the agg and the agg is closed at the end.